# How do I open blue chests in Dreamstones?

Tags: godfall

I found these chests at the end of additional Dreamstone missions (ones that are not 1 huge boss battle) and I cannot just open them with <kbd>◯</kbd>. They have some blue glow around them:

[image]

How do I open them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they work the same as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzZBXGlYep0&ab_channel=MassiveTriggerGaming), you need to destroy these shiny blue items scattered around the surroundings:

[image]

There could be more than 1 such lanterns for each chest. Blue particles from the chest will show direction to them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's correct answer! I also figured out that particles from the chest will show directions to these lanterns

Comment: Also because of that linked video I found completely new in-game mechanic - Spirit Vision - which helps to find chests and other loot

Comment: @arghtype good to know!